# play a downloaded mp3 in xamarin forms

Tags: audio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am able to play a file "test.mp3" added as a resource into the "Resources\Sounds\" folder of my pcl project by calling

`AudioManager.Audio.Manager.PlaySound("test.mp3");`

Now I am trying to play an audio file that I have downloaded from my webapi service. I am using the RestSharp library to download the file and the PCLStorage library to store the file:

```
try
            {
                var fileId = new Guid("test2");
                IFolder rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
                IFolder resources = await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync("Resources", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
                IFolder soundsFolder = await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync("Sounds", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
                IFile myFile = await soundsFolder.CreateFileAsync($"{fileId}.mp3", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
                using (var stream = await myFile.OpenAsync(fileAccess: FileAccess.ReadAndWrite))
                {

                var request = new RestRequest($"{fileId}");
                var client = new RestClient();
                client.BaseUrl = new System.Uri("http://10.0.2.2/MyApp.WebApi/api/");
                var bytes = client.DownloadData(request);
                foreach (var myByte in bytes)
                {
                    stream.WriteByte(myByte);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
```

I also tried saving the file to the root dir but this also doesn't work.

The file seems to download just fine as far as I can tell (no errors). But I have yet to find a way to verify this by locating the file on the android emulator. I guess I first need to install the play store somehow and then download ES File explorer to see the file structure on the android emulator.

The problem is that when I try to play the soundfile in the same way I did with the embedded resource it won't work.

`AudioManager.Audio.Manager.PlaySound("test2.mp3");`

I guess this is because of the magic that happens during compile time to migrate the embedded resources to "somewhere" on the android emulator.
My main problem is that I do not understand what path to use to

- write the file (tried resources/sounds and root)
- read the file (tried
  resources/sounds and root)

in order to be able to play the file

Comment: what is the problem? You cannot save the file or you cannot play it?

Comment: Are you using plugin to play sound in PCL. If yes please tell me which exactly

Comment: Also what platform you are testing on? And when you say "Resources\Sounds" are those in PCL or platform folders?

Comment: I guess you solved that if you are not replying. Would be nice if you post an answer

Comment: I'm using this library to play audio files in my pcl project: https://www.nuget.org/packages/XamarinAudioManager/

@Yuri This is my hobby project so I'm not coding on it every day...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the AudioManager library assumes sounds are always Assets.
In it's [NewSound method in the android code](https://github.com/jcphlux/XamarinAudioManager/blob/master/AudioManager/AudioManager.Droid/DroidAudioManager.cs) it tries to build an AssetFileDescriptor by using the following line:

> Forms.Context.Assets.OpenFd(filePath);

I guess this method wants a filepath relative to the assets folder (for compiled resources) and throws a FileNotFoundException otherwise. This exception, however thrown, did not reach my catch statement in my pcl code. (it looks like it get's swallowed somewhere in the android -> pcl layer??)

Now I am using the SoundPool.LoadAsync with a filepath rather than a AssetFileDescriptor and this fixes my problem.

Yay!